# how to print each line of text file using below Rx.Net code?

Tags: c#, reactive-programming

Problem Statement - I have a file continuously written by a process line by line. I would like a C# solution which will print line by line as soon as it is written by the process.

Solution - I would like to use `Reactive` extension C#, where I will subscribe the stream.

I tried below code, but how to print each line,

```
   stream.Subscribe(e => Console.WriteLine(e.//how to print each line));
```

Here is full code,

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
 using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Files\test_Copy.txt", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var stream = ObserveLines(fs);
            stream.Subscribe(e => Console.WriteLine(e.//how to print each line));
        }
    }

    public static IObservable<string> ObserveLines(Stream inputStream)
    {
        return ReadLines(inputStream).ToObservable(Scheduler.ThreadPool);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(Stream stream)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                yield return reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
 }
```